# How can I achieve initcap functionality in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need the functionality of `initcap` for the region names. Is there any way to achieve this in  MySQL?

- Africa
- India Sub Continent
- U.S. West Coast
- Europe / U.K

in this way the results can be?

Comment: See the comments on the [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) for string functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometime back I was looking for a built-in initcap/ucfirst function in MySQL but unfortunately couldn't find such string functions so decided to write my own.. thanks to the MySQL community member who corrected the bug in my function & posted it back.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`initcap`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initcap`(x char(30)) RETURNS char(30) CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SET @str='';
SET @l_str='';
WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
END WHILE;
RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));
END$$

DELIMITER ;


Usage: 

select initcap('This is test string');
```

Comment: Warning! This function has destroyed my database. I didn't notice that the "return" was a simple 30-character string. All the descriptions in my table had just been truncated to 30 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
   FUNCTION `test`.`initcap`(input VARCHAR(255))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
BEGIN
DECLARE len INT;
DECLARE i INT;

SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
SET input = LOWER(input);
SET i = 0;

WHILE (i < len) DO
    IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
        IF (i < len) THEN
            SET input = CONCAT(
                LEFT(input,i),
                UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
            );
        END IF;
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN input;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

usage:  `initcap("hello world")`
output:  `Hello World`

usage:  `initcap("HELLO WORLD")`
output: `Hello World`

This converts first letter of each word in the string to capital.

Comment: The solutions mentioned previous to this were merely just converting the First Letter of the String. But this one converts First Letter of Each word of the String to Upper Case.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`initcap`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initcap`(x char(30)) RETURNS char(30) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
SET @str='';
SET @l_str='';
WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
END WHILE;
RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `upperfirst`(x varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1

RETURN concat( upper(substring(x,1,1)),lower(substring(x,2)) );
```

Comment: Please clarify your answer.

Comment: This only caps the first character, question is to cap all the words in a string. "HELLO WORLD" converts to "Hello world" with this whereas we need "Hello World".

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL does not provide direct INITCAP function but you can achieve the initcap functionality in MySQL this way:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(column_name, 1, 1),
        LOWER(SUBSTRING(column_name, 2))
    ) AS desired_name
FROM table_name;
```