# Title Case values in SQL database column?

Tags: mysql, database, function

I had a previous question where given a query to change all UPPERCASE values to lowercase ones, within a column in my database table. That works fine.

I am now look as to whether or not it's possible to change values to Title Case (capitalise the first letter)

The possible values will be like so:

```
word
word, word
word-word-word
```

Ideally I would like to be able to change all 'word' instances to Word.

I did find this thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/whats-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s)

But I'm not quite sure how to use the example.

My database name is `exp_channel_data` and the values lie in column `field_id_90`

I'm using Sequel Pro to run the queries.

Thanks.

Comment: This is maybe something you want to do on the view layer, the lowercase as well

Comment: I can, I've tried that, but I also output these values in my meta data, (page title) and then it shows as all lowercase. I have a fairly large table of data, and I have only the one single column that needs to be capitalised. Would just be a bit neater if I could fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I achieve initcap functionality in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql) (The linked post in shorn's question refers to SQLServer, but this is a duplicate of a post for MySQL.)

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to that question. I'm afraid that I'm really not sure how I would go about using that. Not really done anything with databases before.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some regular expression search-and-replace, which is not that well supported in MySQL. Have a look at the answers to this question [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) for some pointers.