# Doing Capital value for field

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql how to make the initcap for the value

```
select ename from emp;

ename
-----
oraCle 
jaVa

o/p
-----
Oracle
Java
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql

Comment: Please specify reason for down vote so people can understand what mistake in answer

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase the first character, lowercase the rest:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(ename, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(ename, 2)))
FROM emp;
```

Comment: Why down vote? it work fine as per user specification

Comment: U did a blind mistake, forgot "from table_name". :(

Comment: I also think this answer but you give answer that's why i do not post

Comment: @Naveen Right, didn't feel that was really necessary though.

Comment: @Jack, not neccessary? then wt abt select and ;?

Comment: @Naveen One would have to be really dense not being able to extract the information from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

***make it simple like this:***

```
SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(MID(ename,1,1)),LCASE(MID(ename,2))) AS ENAME 
FROM emp;
```

***click to sqlfiddle:***

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b75b/2***

Comment: Where did you get different column names from? Also, how is the essence of this answer different than what I have already written 30 minutes earlier?

Comment: what you mean, i can't understand, `How did you get different column names from?`

Comment: OP table name is `emp` and your is `supportContacts`, the name column is `ename` and yours is `type`, how does that work?

Comment: where i mention the table like `emp`.. you should look the sql fiddle

Comment: No, the table used in the question mentions `emp`; you make it `supportContacts` and then introduce some other columns that don't exist in the question either.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(ename, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(ename, 2)))
FROM emp;
```

Comment: This is exactly my answer?