# sql select query returns capitalized

Tags: mysql, sql, select

is there any possibilities that the select query of an mysql returns string with capitalized?

for example for getting the selected query field must be return in lowercase will do

```
SELECT LCASE(name) FROM Person;
```

this will return

```
name
-------
mark miguel
john
james
...
```

by the way, I have a Table named `Person` and the field `name` got all the values in uppercased...

```
name
-------
MARK MIGUEL
JOHN
JAMES
...
```

my question is, is there a select query that has the same function with `LCASE()` that only returns capitalized? for example the returned value will look like this?

```
name
-------
Mark Miguel
John
James
...
```

Comment: By "capitalized" do you mean [Title Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case#Title_case)?

Comment: have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql).

Comment: yes... something like that... like the 1st letter of a word is uppercase and the rest is lowercase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proper;
SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION proper( str VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE punct CHAR(18) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_\'!@;:?/'; -- David Rabby & Lenny Erickson added \'
  SET s = LCASE( str );
  WHILE i <= LENGTH( str ) DO -- Jesse Palmer corrected from < to <= for last char
    BEGIN
      SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
      IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
        SET bool = 1;
      ELSEIF bool=1 THEN 
        BEGIN
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN 
            BEGIN
              SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
              SET bool = 0;
            END;
          ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
            SET bool = 0;
          END IF;
        END;
      END IF;
      SET i = i+1;
    END;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN s;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
select proper("d'arcy");
+------------------+
| proper("d'arcy") |
+------------------+
| D'Arcy           |
+------------------+
```

see http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#122