# Change Case to Upper & Lower in SQL Query SELECT

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Query to pull a customer name from database, create a customer folder with that name.  In the query I am killing slashes and periods, and i am also changing any result containing MCDONALD to SIMPLY "MCDONALDS".  So MCDONALDS #123 comes out as simply MCDONALDS.  Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('MCDONALD', cust_name) = 0
        THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([cust_name],'.',''),'--','-')
        ELSE 'MCDONALDS'
    END  cust_name
FROM job,dbo.cust cust_name
WHERE job.cust_id_bill_to = cust_name.cust_code AND
job.job_id = '44321' AND
job.sub_job_id = '2'
```

So, results now are:

> ```
> MCDONALDS,
> BRISTOL-MYERS,
> TRUMP-CASINO
> ```

Desired results is upper and lower case in every word.. like this:

> ```
> Mcdonalds,
> Bristol-Myers,
> Trump-Casino
> ```

I know its easy but for me its how to have it work WITH the rest of my query, what I am trying just not working so far.

Comment: `Mysql`<>`Sql Server`. Choose one

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check Nimit Dudani Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql)

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`initcap`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initcap`(x char(30)) RETURNS char(30) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
SET @str='';
SET @l_str='';
WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
END WHILE;
RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

select initcap('This is test string');

Comment: Thanks, but I am not familiar with how to deploy and apply this answer. I am just at a more basic level with SQL and haven't seen or used this level of programming when reformatting results. So, when I run the query example here, it returns error.

Comment: ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '$'.
Error Code: 102

'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: ALSO, I notice in my query example I had two THEN, second one should have said ELSE.  Can you please show me or explain to me the full implementation of your answer with my sample query.  TIA, I thank you for your valuable time and Merry Christmas to you!

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server you can use [**this**](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/initcap)

`INITCAP` User defined Function code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InitCap') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.InitCap;
  GO

 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitCap (@inStr VARCHAR(8000))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @outStr VARCHAR(8000) = LOWER(@inStr),
         @char CHAR(1), 
         @alphanum BIT = 0,
         @len INT = LEN(@inStr),
                 @pos INT = 1;        

    -- Iterate through all characters in the input string
    WHILE @pos <= @len BEGIN

      -- Get the next character
      SET @char = SUBSTRING(@inStr, @pos, 1);

      -- If the position is first, or the previous characater is not alphanumeric
      -- convert the current character to upper case
      IF @pos = 1 OR @alphanum = 0
        SET @outStr = STUFF(@outStr, @pos, 1, UPPER(@char));

      SET @pos = @pos + 1;

      -- Define if the current character is non-alphanumeric
      IF ASCII(@char) <= 47 OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 58 AND 64) OR
      (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 91 AND 96) OR (ASCII(@char) BETWEEN 123 AND 126)
      SET @alphanum = 0;
      ELSE
      SET @alphanum = 1;

    END

   RETURN @outStr;         
  END
  GO
```

**Testing :**

```
SELECT dbo.InitCap('new york');
```

**Result:**  New York

For your query

```
SELECT 
    dbo.InitCap(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('MCDONALD', cust_name) = 0
                    THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([cust_name],'.',''),'--','-')
                    THEN 'MCDONALDS'
               END)  cust_name
FROM job,dbo.cust cust_name
WHERE job.cust_id_bill_to = cust_name.cust_code AND
job.job_id = '44321' AND
job.sub_job_id = '2'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not familiar with how to deploy and apply this answer.  I am just at a more basic level with SQL and haven't seen or used this level of programming when reformatting results.  So, when I run the query example here, it returns error.

Comment: ERROR: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined 
function or aggregate "dbo.InitCap", or the name is ambiguous. 
Error Code: 4121

Comment: ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
Error Code: 102

Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Comment: NOTE, I notice in my query example I had two THEN, second one should have said ELSE. Can you please show me or explain to me the full implementation of your answer with my sample query. I tried running it pasted atop my other query but it did not fly.  I am not sure how to put it all into the final proper query.  TIA, I appreciate your time and Merry Christmas to you and your family!

Comment: First tell which RDBMS you are using `Mysql` or `Sql server`