# MYSQL - Format name string with separators

Tags: mysql

I would like to format a name string in a SQL INSERT statement. The name string can contain multiple versions of whitespaces (' '), dash ('-') and dot ('.'). The name string should be formatted with the first letter capitalized. See the following examples:

- john doe -> John Doe
- AL ARMIN can -> Al Armin Can
- math-LY HAROUN -> Math-Ly Haroun
- St. john -> St. John

Finding one special character is possible, but finding a combination is the difficult part. I would appreciate any ideas.

Maybe it would make sense to check if the string is already properly formatted, but only if that would simplify things.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I used something like CASE WHEN firstname LIKE '%-%' to locate single special character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I achieve initcap functionality in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql)

Comment: Try with a combination as in [Initcap][1]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. The Initcap function started me on the right path. I would like to share the code that I used, which does exactly what I need it to do. This also works with Umlaute and checks for whitespace, dot and dash.

```
function initCap($string){
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $return_string ='';
    $pattern='/[\wäöüÄÖÜßáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+[\s\.\-]+/';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $string)){
        while(preg_match($pattern,$string,$temp_array,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,strlen($return_string))){
            if(stripos($temp_array[0][0],'von ')===0 ||stripos($temp_array[0][0],'der ')===0){
                $return_string.=strtolower($temp_array[0][0]);
            }else {
                $convert = mb_strtolower($temp_array[0][0]);
                $return_string .= mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($convert,0,1)).mb_substr($convert,1);
            }
        }
        $return_string.=ucfirst(strtolower(substr($string,strlen($return_string))));

    } else {
        $convert = mb_strtolower($string);
        $return_string = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($convert,0,1)).mb_substr($convert,1);
    }
    return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: Any improvements on the function are more then welcome.