# SQL Replace characters in a single column only. joe.bloggs to Joe Bloggs

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I figured id start with this;

```
UPDATE wp_users
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, '.',' ')
```

But then i realised nowhere can i specify its only one column i want to affect, the *display_name* column, first i need to replace a '.' with a ' ' (space), then i want to either replace a with A, or assuming that'd be alot of duplicated SQL, capitalise first letter of each word.

Im using MySQL with wordpress

Summary: Data is currently:

```
**display_name**
joe.bloggs
sally.sue
timmy.turner
```

I need to get it to be:

```
**display_name**
Joe Bloggs
Sally Sue
Timmy Turner
```

Comment: Add sample data (different name versions), and the expected result. As well formatted text.

Comment: What about adding Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien and Carl van der Walt?

Comment: @jarlh and Jonathan Rhys-Davies

Comment: Im sorry im not sure whats happening here :p @jarlh

Comment: @JohnHC, forgot that one, thanks!

Comment: @Kieronboz Names that fit a non-standard format, like Mc, O', van der and hyphenated, how would those be handled? How would they be stored? Also, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql) for an idea on initcap functionality in mysql

Comment: Ah, well the user list is only 200 or so long, this is just to run once at first auto-registration, so list is populated, run this, fix the few that break, from then on process is going to be manual, one every so often, so i didn't mention anything other than a plain name format, as it fits my use case :-) @jarlh

Comment: I  have one attempt but name like john.doe.van will be John Van , works perfectly with 2 normal names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is really bad with these things. I used substring index , left, right and some concatenation to make the following. It look bit ugly but works. 
**It wont works for name like van.der.sar**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',
    CONCAT(
                UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',1),1)),
               RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',1),length(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',1))-1)
        ),
       CONCAT(
                UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',-1),1)),
               RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',-1),length(SUBSTRING_INDEX('john.doe','.',-1))-1)
        )           
       )
```

so your update script should be like below

```
Update wp_users set name = CONCAT_WS(' ',
        CONCAT(
                    UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',1),1)),
                   RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',1),length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',1))-1)
            ),
           CONCAT(
                    UCASE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',-1),1)),
                   RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',-1),length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'.',-1))-1)
            )           
           )
```

Comment: It will be nice to upvote the answer which helped you :)