# Make first word of a letter in all the values in database to uppercase using query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a row in database, If i write this query

```
select * from table1;
```

The following query will give the desired result

```
james anderson
stuart broad
```

Can i have the query where the first letter of the word should be in Uppercase

i.e the output must be

**J**ames **A**nderson

**S**tuart **B**road

Have tried with following query

```
UPDATE people_table SET full_name = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(full_name,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTR(full_name,2)));
```

This query yields only the first Word of the row in uppercase.

Comment: Can there be only one space between the first name and last name?

Comment: yes only one space

Comment: try the solution given on this link-  http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this kind of thing before, it's referred to as an INITCAP function.

It's not a built in function but [check this link out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql) for some mysql examples.

Have pasted the solution from this below:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`initcap`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initcap`(x char(30)) RETURNS char(30) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
SET @str='';
SET @l_str='';
WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
END WHILE;
RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
select initcap('This is test string');
```

I'm assuming you're familiar with user defined functions, but to use this in an update it'd be kinda like:

```
update myTable set name = initcap(name) where ...
```

Hope this is helpful!